# Is it impossible to split a convergent sequence into an odd number of divergent sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Motivation: Suppose we have the constant sequence $1$, then it's limit can be written as $\lim_{ n \to \infty} (n+1 -n)$. So, an example of a convergent sequence split into two divergent sequences.

We could also think of the same example as if we are doing a three way split , $\{ 1 \}  = \{ -n \}_n + \{ n+1 \}_n + \{0 \}$, then even now when we've split a convergent sequence into three sequences, where two are divergent.

I believe this extends more generally, **that if we split a sequence into some number of other sequences, then always the divergence should come in pairs so as to cancel out. How do I prove this?**

---

### My try

Suppose we have a convergent sequence $\{s_i \}_i$ split as a sum of sequences $\sum_j \{ a_{ji} \}_i$, then we can split the sum as $\sum_{j \in \text{ convergent seequences} }  \{ a_{ji} \}_i + \sum_{j \in \text{ divergent seequences} }  \{ a_{ji} \}_i$. The sum of any number convergent sequences is again convergent. We have,

$$ \lim_{i \to \infty} s_i - \sum_{j \in \text{convergent sequences} } \{ a_{ji} \}_i= \sum_{j \in \text{ divergent seequences} }  \{ a_{ji} \}_i$$

Since LHS converges, RHS converges. We have to just show that there is no contradiction if the number of divergent sequence is even... but I'm not sure how.

Comment: I wonder if $\{ \}$ should enclose the sum or not

Comment: You can always "split" a divergent sequence $a_n$ into $2$ divergent ones, for example $a_n/2$ and $a_n/2$.

Comment: I had many typos in the post, I edited now, check again pls @dxiv

Comment: Same comment still applies. If $u_n=a_n+b_n$ is a split in $2$ divergent sequences (even), then also $u_n=a_n+b_n/2+b_n/2$ is a split into $3$ divergent sequences (odd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to split a convergent sequence into the sum of an odd number of divergent sequences. For example, you can split up the sequence $\{1\}_n$ into:

$$a_n = n/2, \quad b_n = n/2, \quad c_n = 1 -n$$

Comment: Well damn :(...